# How to get browser window front while running the test using selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

How to get Firefox browser window front while running the test using selenium C#?

Comment: means? is the execution window/browser not displaying on screen as active?

Comment: Hi Murali, Thanks for the reply, no the browser is running on background I just want that execution browser on front. for example I'm working on excel while running the test browser run background.

Comment: as known active window displayed on screen. so if you work on excel then surely selenium execution browser on back.

Comment: then how can i switch to the active window while the test run?

Comment: Why does it matter whether the script is in the foreground or not? The script will run anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If while running script any new opened window is not active then you can use

```
getDriver().switchTo().window("your window name");
```

Comment: Follow up questions to the OP are best posted as a comment on the question.

Comment: @DesHorsley this isn't a follow up question, it's an answer that should solve OP's issue.

Comment: @JeffC, I was referring to the original answer, it's been edited.

Comment: It doesn't work  I get no such windows error